# Choose your own adventure homework assignment

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have to complete a choose your own adventure game, and I am at a complete loss as to why I don't see anything appearing in my browser. I have a data structure that has an image for the current page then two options. The two options take you either 1 step ahead or 2 steps ahead besides the last one. For some reason I cannot get it to run, and I know that it is probably just a tiny mistake somewhere.

```
    <!doctype html>
        <html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="adventureStylez.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.12.0.js">
        var adventureGame = [
            {
                "src": "http://people.emich.edu/egurnee/assets/dixit/books.jpg",
                "desc": "You find yourself overwhelmed with homework. You must relieve yourself of stress before you can even begin to accomplish anything. What do you do?",
                "loc": 0,
                "type": "choice",
                "choices": [
                    {
                        "desc": "Attempt some math homework.",
                        "loc": 1
                    },
                    {
                        "desc": "Go for a calming night walk on the dock by the ocean.",
                        "loc": 2
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "src": "http://people.emich.edu/egurnee/assets/dixit/math.jpg",
                "desc": "The attempt to complete math homework resulted in more stress. Now what do you do?",
                "loc": 1,
                "type": "choice",
                "choices": [
                    {
                        "desc": "Go for a calming night walk on the dock by the ocean.",
                        "loc": 2
                    },
                    {
                        "desc": "Paint a picture.",
                        "loc": 3
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "src": "http://people.emich.edu/egurnee/assets/dixit/dock.jpg",
                "desc": "The dock is very unstable. You must hold your balance, but you are having trouble with it. What do you do?",
                "loc": 2,
                "type": "choice",
                "choices": [
                    {
                        "desc": "Go back home and paint a picture.",
                        "loc": 3
                    },
                    {
                        "desc": "Use your inner zen energy to persevere and finish the walk on the dock.",
                        "loc": 4
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "src": "http://people.emich.edu/egurnee/assets/dixit/tree.jpg",
                "desc": "You paint a beautiful of a girl and a tree. Now you feel bored. What do you do?",
                "loc": 3,
                "type": "choice",
                "choices": [
                    {
                        "desc": "Use your inner zen energy to conquer that dock.",
                        "loc": 4
                    },
                    {
                        "desc": "Go beat that metal octopus' ass that has been harassing your dog at night.",
                        "loc": 5
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "src": "http://people.emich.edu/egurnee/assets/dixit/balance.jpg",
                "desc": "You made that dock your bitch. All of a sudden you feel an intense amount of adrenaline. What do you do?",
                "loc": 4,
                "type": "choice",
                "choices": [
                    {
                        "desc": "Jump in the ocean.",
                        "loc": 6
                    },
                    {
                        "desc": "Go beat that metal octopus' ass that has been harassing your dog at night.",
                        "loc": 5
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "src": "http://people.emich.edu/egurnee/assets/dixit/metaloctopus.jpg",
                "desc": "That octopus is done for. Congratulations you have won!",
                "loc": 5,
                "type": "choice",
                "choices": [
                    {
                        "desc": "Play again?",
                        "loc": 0
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "src": "http://people.emich.edu/egurnee/assets/dixit/sad-bear.jpg",
                "desc": "Oh, no! When you jumped in the ocean you were eaten by a shark. Try again.",
                "loc": 6,
                "type": "choice",
                "choices": [
                    {
                        "desc": "Try again?",
                        "loc": 0
                    }
                ]
            }
        ];

        function add_choice(desc, loc) {
            $("#response").append("<button class=choice data-loc=" + loc + ">" + desc + "</button>");
        }

        function set_page_desc(desc) {
            $("#page_desc").append("<p>" + desc + "</p>");
        }

        function set_page_img(src){
            $("#page_img").append("<img src =\" " + src + "\">")
        }


        function clear_page() {
            $("#page_desc").empty();
            $("#response").empty();
        }
        function load_page(id) {
            // Fetch JSON for page data associated with given ID
            var page_data = adventureGame[id];

            clear_page();
            set_page_img(page_data.src);
            set_page_desc(page_data.desc);
            if (page_data.type === 'choice') {
                for (var choice in page_data.choices) {
                    var choice_data = page_data.choices[choice];
                    add_choice(choice_data.desc, choice_data.loc);
                }
            }
        }


        var current_page = 0;
        $(document).ready(function () {
            load_page(0);
            $('#response').on('click', '.choice', function () {
                var loc = $(this).data('loc');
                load_page(loc);
            });
        });
    </script>
    <title>My Choose Your Own Adventure Game</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.12.0.js">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            load_page(0);
            $('#response').on('click', '.choice', function () {
                var loc = $(this).data('loc');
                load_page(loc);
            });
        });
    </script>
    <div id="page" class="blockCenter">
    <div id="page_img"></div>
    <div id="page_desc"></div>
    <div id="response"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does the browser console have any errors logged?

Comment: No, there are no errors.

Comment: You have two $(document).ready functions that essentially do the same thing and you've added a src attribute to your body script tag.

Comment: You've merged the script in which you include jQuery, and the one where your hand-written script goes. They're using the same tag.
Also. There are two the exact same scripts. Remove one of them.

Comment: Removed the one in the body, but I am still getting a blank screen.

Comment: You should mark one of the answers as accepted; it should probably be @GustvandeWal but I wouldn't be upset if it was me :)

Comment: Considering @GriffinObeid only has 1 reputation, I do not think he can yet accept answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that your script tags are not setup correctly.

This script tag `<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.12.0.js">` has your local javascript and a reference to jquery as well.  It should be one or the other, but not both.

So first, you would want to do this.  You can change the src to be local, or a CDN, but that will include jQuery for you.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    your code goes here
</script>
```

A second issue is that you have two document ready functions.  You should only have one; and where it is located is debated, but it is commonly found at the bottom of your page just before you closing body tag.

So your code would look something like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="adventureStylez.css">
        <title>My Choose Your Own Adventure Game</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="page" class="blockCenter">
            <div id="page_img"></div>
            <div id="page_desc"></div>
            <div id="response"></div>
        </div>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.12.0.js">
            //Other JS Code from top of page

            var current_page = 0;
            $(document).ready(function () {
                load_page(0);
                $('#response').on('click', '.choice', function () {
                   var loc = $(this).data('loc');
                   load_page(loc);
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you that was the solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.12.0.js">
    // Your code
</script>
```

Your problem is this. You've written a script tag, in which you `src` jquery, but you've also written your own code.
Write this instead:

```
<script src="jquery-1.12.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Your code
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you that was the solution.